# Scrapy CrawlerProcess Not Saving Data with CrawlSpider

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

The following code will execute, create the file with no errors. However, it is not saving to the json file.

I turned off autothrottle, which in the past has interfered with downloading data, but it didn't fix the issue.

Scrapy==1.4.0

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "spidy"
    allowed_domains = ["cnn.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.cnn.com"]    

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['cnn.com/.+']), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]    

    def parse_item(self, response):

        print('went to: {}'.format(response.url))

        yield {'url': response.url}         

FILE_NAME = 'my_data.json'
SETTINGS = {
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
            'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
            'FEED_URI': FILE_NAME,          
            } 

process = CrawlerProcess(SETTINGS)
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

EDIT:

The scraper is getting the data as seen in the log:

```
2017-11-21 11:07:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-11-21 11:07:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)', 'FEED_URI': 'my_data.json', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json'}
2017-11-21 11:07:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter']
2017-11-21 11:07:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-11-21 11:07:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-11-21 11:07:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-11-21 11:07:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-11-21 11:07:55 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-11-21 11:07:55 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6041
2017-11-21 11:07:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com> (referer: None)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/us> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/specials/politics/congress-capitol-hill> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/specials/politics/president-donald-trump-45> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/specials/politics/us-security> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/specials/politics/trumpmerica> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/specials/politics/state-cnn-politics-magazine> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/specials/opinion/opinion-social-issues> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/specials/opinions/cnnireport> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/specials/vr/vr-archives> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/middle-east> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://imagesource.cnn.com> from <GET http://www.cnn.com/collection>
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.cnn.com/specials/politics/supreme-court-nine> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/> from <GET http://www.cnn.com/transcripts>
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://money.cnn.com/pf/> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://money.cnn.com/luxury/> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://money.cnn.com/data/markets/> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://money.cnn.com/technology/> (referer: http://www.cnn.com)
went to: http://www.cnn.com/us
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.cnn.com/us>
{'url': 'http://www.cnn.com/us'}
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.cnn.com/us> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2017-11-21 11:07:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.cnn.com/email/subscription> from <GET http://www.cnn.com/newsletters>
...
```

We can see the scraper is visiting the URLs, crawling additional urls on the page, getting the response URL (as see with "went to: ") then returning the data with "{'url':}, e.g. {'url': 'http://www.cnn.com/us'}

Comment: @eLRuLL Please see the edit. I added the log.

Comment: @ethanenglish try making `FEED_URI` an absolute path `/directory/subdirectory/file.json` or an actual URI `file:///directory/subdirectory/file.json` ?

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the suggestion. I added it in but alas it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @JonClements It will save with a relative path when the parse method is used but once I use parse_item, it doesn't save.

Comment: I’ve used your code, simply adding missing imports and using an absolute path for 'FILE_NAME', and it works.

Comment: @Gallaecio - What version were you using?

Comment: I’m using 1.5.2

Comment: I think it was a bug in my version because it worked in previous versions. Thanks for jumping in!

Answer (score 1):

So your code as such works fine, but I assume you stop it twice or kill it which makes the json blank. I would change two things.

One use `jsonlines` instead of `json`. This would make sure that even if I kill the spider I won't loose too many items. Then each line itself is a valid JSON, so I can append to same file. Also if you break the program in between you will get a invalid JSON

Second, I would set the concurrent items to a lower value so items are exported more often (Default value is 100)

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from scrapy.linkextractor import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "spidy"
    allowed_domains = ["cnn.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.cnn.com"]

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['cnn.com/.+']), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        print('went to: {}'.format(response.url))

        yield {'url': response.url}

FILE_NAME = 'my_data.jsonl'
SETTINGS = {
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
            'FEED_FORMAT': 'jsonlines',
            'FEED_URI': FILE_NAME,
            'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 1
            }

process = CrawlerProcess(SETTINGS)
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

After that you will find the data does get exported fine

[image: items exported]

Comment: That's really odd. Your code should work but scrapy creates the file gets the data but doesn't save it to the file. I'm completely lost here. I've uninstalled and installed the module, tried different import methods, still nothing.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Latest version of Mac Sierra

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? If not please use one and then try

Comment: I added the virtual env with Scrapy==1.4.0 installed and all dependencies.

Comment: I can save data when I use the parse function with scrapy.Spider but the second I add parse_item in conjunction with rules for a CrawlSpider it stops saving.